# Set image as background of figure container

Tags: jquery, html

I would like to set the image from the src-tag as the background of the figure container dynamically with jquery.

```
<figure><img class="cam" id="c125228" src="http://www.adamelloski.com/images/ImportAutomatico/WebCam/tonale.jpg" alt="Passo Tonale 1883m" /><figcaption>Passo Tonale 1883m</figcaption></figure>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do this way:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

var source = $("img.cam").attr("src");

$("img.cam").closest("figure").css("background-image","url("+source+")");

    })
```

[**FIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/9hKX3/19/)

Comment: Nice! and when I have multiple figure tags with images?

Comment: then you have to iterate and set one by one